# Change in the behavior of the Edit controls when receiving the Focus, due to migration from Genexus 17 to Genexus 18

Tags: genexus

When migrating from `Genexus 17` to `Genexus 18` the behavior when selecting or clicking Edit (Control) changed. In `GX17`, when clicking on an Edit, the cursor was placed at the position of the content of the Edit where it was clicked, while now in `GX18`, clicking automatically selects all the content of the Edit, without being able to edit with the mouse. How could I configure in `GX18` the above behavior as in `GX17`? (We use the Java environment), thank you.